# Building Fortran extension for Python 3.5 or C extension for 2.7

Tags: python, c++, boost, fortran, gfortran

I have a Python 2.7 project that has thus far been using gfortran and MinGW to build extensions. I use MinGW because it seems to support write statements and allocatable arrays in the Fortran code while MSVC does not.

There is another project I would like to incorporate into my own (Netgen) but it is currently set up for Python 3.5 using Boost.Python. I first tried to transfer my own program to Python 3.5 but that is where I was reminded of the MSVC issues and apparently MinGW is not supported. For that reason, I've been trying to think of a way to compile Netgen + Boost.Python for deployment in Python 2.7.

I think the Boost part is straightforward, but it seems I need Visual C++ 2008 to get it integrated with Python 2.7. I have the Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7 from Microsoft, but I haven't gotten it to work inside the CMake build system. I point it to the cl.exe compilers in the VC for Python folders and CMake always tells me that building a simple test program fails. Since I don't actually have (and can't find) Visual Studio 2008, not sure how far I'd get anyway.

There's a lot of places that could have issues here, but I'm just looking for a go/no-go answer if that's what it is. Any solutions would obviously be welcomed.

I am running Windows 10 64-bit.

I'm not a C/C++ expert, but it seems like I have all the tools I need to compile Netgen using the VC for Python tools (cl, link, etc). I just don't have/not sure how to put it all together into a project or something like that.

Comment: Try to select tags which are more relevant and have more followers. [tag:fortran] is one of them

Answer (score 0):

I built Boost.Python libraries 1.61.0 from source for Python 2.7 using VC 14.0. Then used those in the build process for Netgen (again using VC 14.0) and pointed to the Python 2.7 library and include directories (as opposed to Python 3.5). This has thus far worked in Python 2.7 with my existing code.

Comment: Is this meant to be a comment or answer to your own question?